# Rails form tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form to allow the user to upload an image file, but i currently have it in text format, so they enter the file name of the image, but i would like to have it so they click a select button to upload the file rather than typing it in, and then when the file is selected from their hard drive, it will show in the textbox next to the button, thanks.

```
<%= form_for(@question) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :question %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :question, autofocus: true %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :description %><br/>
    <%= f.text_area :description, cols: 40, rows: 7 %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :posted_by %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :posted_by, size: 5 %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :image_file_name %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :image_file_name, size: 30, placeholder: 'GIF, JPG, or PNG file' %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :posted_at %><br/>
    <%= f.date_select :posted_at %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
    <%= link_to('Cancel', questions_path) %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `file_field` instead of `text_field` which allows to upload a file.

`<%= f.file_field :image_file_name,accept: 'image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg',:multiple => true %>`

**`:multiple`** - If set to true, *in most updated browsers* the user will be allowed to select multiple files.

**`:accept`** - If set to one or multiple mime-types, the user will be suggested a filter when choosing a file. You still need to set up model validations.

For more details, see this [**API**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/file_field)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `file_field` instead of `text_field`.

```
<%= f.text_field :image_file_name, accept: 'image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg' %>
```

See more: [FormHelper.html#method-i-file_field](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-file_field)

Answer (score 0):

An answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10526674/786709

(source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files)