# Is it correct to specify ":html => { :multipart => true}" for form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, form-for, multipartform-data

We're running Rails 3.2.19 and Ruby 2.1.2.

We have a legacy line of code (actually, more than one, but this line is of particular concern) that reads

`form_for [@commentable, @comment], :html => { :multipart => true, :class => "lightbox_form"} do |f|`

The form data may or may not include an uploaded file at the user's discretion.

Many examples in SO refer to specifying the `:multipart` setting, but then I see this answer at [Form_for with :multipart => true spits out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526641/form-for-with-multipart-true-spits-out) and then in looking at the docs at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.19/form_helpers.html#uploading-files, I see that it shouldn't be necessary (except if using `form_tag`).   I also see this discussion at https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10176 that adds to my confusion.

I'm asking in part because we're getting EOF errors in Rack (no content coming through on the multipart parser; see [Rack throwing EOFError (bad content body)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25874529/rack-throwing-eoferror-bad-content-body) if you're interested in those details).

Our code may have been previously run under earlier versions of Rails when it may have been necessary (and so may just be a holdover).  But given all the other examples on SO that include `:multipart`, I want to better understand if or when `:multipart` is needed with `form_for` before I remove it and what side effects I may encounter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not required in Rails 3.1 and later, as long as you're using `form_for` with `file_field` like this:

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :picture %>
<% end %>
```

This will not work:

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
  <%= file_field_tag 'person[picture]' %>
<% end %>
```

You can easily verify that it's working. Inspect the generated HTML and look for the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute on the form tag. Rails doesn't do any magic beyond setting the encoding type, so if the attribute is there, you're good.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  So then it appears that adding `:multipart` is simply extraneous for `form_for` (given the condition you gave).  Or does it actually change behavior to include it if it's not otherwise needed (like forcing multipart when it might otherwise not be used)?

Comment: Including it will set the form to be multipart always, even when it's unnecessary. Leaving it out, the attribute will only be set if a `form_builder.file_field` triggers multipart mode.